# Null Pointer Exception, Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is my LogCat Error Mesage

```
01-26 15:06:44.996    6571-6571/com.rnhb.vishwas.sw E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rnhb.vishwas.sw, PID: 6571
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.rnhb.vishwas.sw.OrgModel com.rnhb.vishwas.sw.DBAdapter.getOrg(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.rnhb.vishwas.sw.OneFragment.onActivityCreated(OneFragment.java:27)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1797)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:979)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is a method on DBAdapter Class

```
public OrgModel getOrg(String EmailId) {
        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM ORG_TB WHERE EMAIL='" + EmailId + "'  ";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();


        OrgModel orgModel = new OrgModel();
        orgModel.setFull_Name(cursor.getString(1));
        orgModel.setEmail(cursor.getString(2));
        orgModel.setPassword(cursor.getString(3));
        orgModel.setLocation(cursor.getString(4));
        orgModel.setContact(cursor.getString(5));

        return orgModel;

    }
```

And I am trying to fetch value from a fragment and code is

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        String Email=pref.getString("EMAIL_ID", null);
        Log.d("Email is:", Email);
        OrgModel mymod =dbAdapter.getOrg(Email);
        String pass=mymod.getPassword().toString();
        Log.d("Password is",pass);

    }
```

And this is a OrgModel Class

```
public class OrgModel {
    String Email;
    String Password;
    String Contact;
    String Location;
    String Full_Name;

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return Contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        Contact = contact;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return Location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        Location = location;
    }

    public String getFull_Name() {
        return Full_Name;
    }

    public void setFull_Name(String full_Name) {
        Full_Name = full_Name;
    }



}
```

Don't know where I did mistake .I want to print All the values in a row of that user from database into a fragment according to the email that is retrieved from a session value.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Guess you didn't initialize "dbAdapter". Try initializing it before this statement OrgModel mymod = dbAdapter.getOrg(Email)

Comment: Where is the initialization of dbAdapter?

Comment: I forget to mention it on code but It was initialized above @override and inside the class like this DBAdapter dbAdapter;

Comment: you have declared it, have you used any statement like this `dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(context)` etc

Comment: No, I haven't use that. Should i use it inside the onActivityCreated method?